# Timeout on Heroku push with a custom/private gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timeout, bundler

I am currently trying to use a custom/private gem that is hosted on GitHub in my Heroku app however whenever I try to push to Heroku it hangs when it is Bundling the gem.

To get the private gem working I have been using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13261333/1031875) and created a token for accessing the repository.

All works extremely well locally and my `bundle` commands works a charm however the minute I push to Heroku, it will hang when it gets to fetching the custom gem. Here is the output (censored for sensitive info):

```
Counting objects: 26, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 2.49 KiB, done.
Total 19 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.5
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs     vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Updating git://github.com/rails/rails.git
       Fetching https://<token>@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git

       <hangs here with Heroku timeout error>
```

It seems I am having similar problems to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560481/timeout-when-pushing-to-heroku) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623042/heroku-push-failing-perhaps-timeout-from-rubygems) however I have tried both of the solutions proposed on those questions to no avail.

I am using `edge-rails` so I thought that the use of `bundler 1.3.0.pre.5` might be the problem as locally I am using `1.2.3`. Would forcing a `bundler` version on Heroku possibly work? Also I am not sure why there are two `Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..` lines either...

Thanks a million for your help, been pulling my hair out at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem ended up being that the version of `git` Heroku uses doesn't support using tokens yet! Once I included a username/password in my Gemfile (not happy about that but I have set up a special collaborator account so the security risk is narrowed somewhat...) it worked perfectly!

A special thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964196/pulling-in-authenticated-git-repos-on-heroku/13173442#13173442) that I found that helped me out :)